# Selectbox multilevel

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am currently making an product page. I need a selectbox displaying multilevels
of categories where to add the product in. Need something like (php/mysql dynamic):

```
<option>Workstations</option>
<option>--Macs</option>
<option>--Windows</option>
<option>Software</option>
<option>--Image editing</option>
<option>----Pro</option>
<option>----Semi pro</option>
```

My mysql fields are, cat_id, cat_name, cat_parent.
I have the following code, so is there any way to customize it to work with a selectbox insted of ul/li?

```
function display_children($parent, $level) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT a.id, a.label, a.link, Deriv1.Count FROM `menu` a  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `menu` GROUP BY parent) Deriv1 ON a.id = Deriv1.parent WHERE a.parent=" . $parent);
    echo "<ul>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row['Count'] > 0) {
            echo "<li><a href='" . $row['link'] . "'>" . $row['label'] . "</a>";
            display_children($row['id'], $level + 1);
            echo "</li>";
        } elseif ($row['Count']==0) {
            echo "<li><a href='" . $row['link'] . "'>" . $row['label'] . "</a></li>";
        } else;
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

display_children(0, 1);
```

Regards, Simon

Comment: Are you sure you want to do navigation with a select?  That wouldn't be a very user-friendly way of doing it.  A list that the user can drill down into is more typical.

Comment: Also, you really don't want to be using mysql_* for database interaction.  It's all but deprecated.  You should be looking at mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: It is possible that he wants to use multiple selects?  Eg. One for Workstations, one for Software??  Please help us to help you.

Comment: It's a page for an admin site, so that's why i need a multilevel selectbox!!! :-) You guys are right if it was for a normal front end it would not be very un-userfriendly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
function display_children($parent, $level) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT a.id, a.label, a.link, Deriv1.Count FROM `menu` a  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `menu` GROUP BY parent) Deriv1 ON a.id = Deriv1.parent WHERE a.parent=" . $parent);

    $indent = str_repeat('-', $level);
    $tpl = '<option value="%s">%s</option>';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo sprintf($tpl, $row['link'], $indent . $row['label']);

        if ($row['Count'] > 0) {
            display_children($row['id'], $level + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I think you could also simplify your query slightly

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT a.id, a.label, a.link, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `menu` WHERE parent = a.id) AS Count FROM `menu` a  WHERE a.parent=" . $parent);
```

**Reworked example**

The following would allow you to complete the whole process with 1 query. It uses PHP 5.3 due to closures.

```
// I assume this is how your data comes out of MySQL
$items = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'label' => 'Item One',  'link' => 'Link One',    'parent' => 0),
    array('id' => 2, 'label' => 'Child One', 'link' => 'Link Two',    'parent' => 1),
    array('id' => 3, 'label' => 'Child Two', 'link' => 'Link Three',  'parent' => 1),
    array('id' => 4, 'label' => 'Item Two',  'link' => 'Link Four',   'parent' => 0),
    array('id' => 5, 'label' => 'Child One',  'link' => 'Link Five',  'parent' => 4),
    array('id' => 6, 'label' => 'Child Two',  'link' => 'Link Six',   'parent' => 4),
    array('id' => 7, 'label' => 'Child Three',  'link' => 'Link Six',   'parent' => 6),
    array('id' => 8, 'label' => 'Child Four',  'link' => 'Link Six',   'parent' => 6),
);

// Loop using references to build a tree
$childs = array();
foreach($items as &$item)
{
    $childs[$item['parent']][] = &$item;
}

unset($item);

foreach($items as &$item)
{
    if(isset($childs[$item['id']]))
    {
        $item['children'] = $childs[$item['id']];
    }
}
// We now have a tree with 'children' key set on each node that has children
$tree = $childs[0];

// Prepare a template and recursive closure (note reference on &$print)
$tpl = '<option value="%s">%s %s</option>';
$print = function($item, $indent = '') use (&$print, $tpl)
{
    echo sprintf($tpl, $item['link'], $indent, $item['label']) . "\n";

    if(isset($item['children']))
    {
        foreach($item['children'] as $child)
        {
            $print($child, $indent . '-');
        }
    }
};

echo '<select onchange="showProduct(this.value);">';
// Call the function for each top-level node
foreach($tree as $row)
{
    $print($row);
}
echo '</select>';

/*
<select onchange="showProduct(this.value);">
<option value="Link One"> Item One</option>
<option value="Link Two">- Child One</option>
<option value="Link Three">- Child Two</option>
<option value="Link Four"> Item Two</option>
<option value="Link Five">- Child One</option>
<option value="Link Six">- Child Two</option>
<option value="Link Six">-- Child Three</option>
<option value="Link Six">-- Child Four</option>
</select>
*/
```

Comment: I do not think i'm quiet sure how to use your code.
How do i display the selectbox in the reworked example? :/

Comment: Just echo it before and after the last `foreach()` block

Comment: it = what? (sry i think my brain is stuck) I really appreciate your help!

Comment: It worked so far with the array. How do i then add the SQL?
I assume that i still need to do a recursive function, or is there an easier way when it's a selectbox?

Comment: All you need is an array full of your entire table data. Something like ``SELECT id, label, link, parent FROM `menu` ``, `mysql_query()` with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and push each row onto the `$items` array

Comment: Hmm. if i try to make what you suggest and then print_r the array outside the assoc, it only echo 1 row :/

Comment: Yes you will need to `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ ... ]` - this is basic mysql knowledge, please [see the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Year i know. I just don't know if I did it correctly?

// I assume this is how your data comes out of MySQL
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_link, cat_parent FROM `categories`");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

 $items2 = array(
  array('id' => $data['cat_id'], 'label' => $data['cat_name'], 'link' => $data['cat_link'], 'parent' => $data['cat_parent'])
 );

}

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_link, cat_parent FROM categories"); 
 $items = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
  $items[] = array('id' => $data['cat_id'], 'label' => $data['cat_name'], 'link' => $data['cat_link'], 'parent' => $data['cat_parent']);
 }

Comment: Damn that worked flawlessly. Thank you so much for your help.
I can se that I need to check out some basic sql knowledge.
Thanks again :-)

Comment: NP, please upvote and mark as answered if your issue is resolved :)

Comment: You should be able to click 'up' next to the answer, and there should be a tick under the arrow

Comment: Sorry for commenting here but i just wondering where do you set $data, as im trying to do the same and i got an undefined variable data..sorry im really a noob

Comment: It's `while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ //... }`

Answer (score 1):

If a select box is all you really want you just need to replace the ul tags with select and li tags with option.

**Modified PHP:**

```
function display_children($parent, $level) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT a.id, a.label, a.link, Deriv1.Count FROM `menu` a  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `menu` GROUP BY parent) Deriv1 ON a.id = Deriv1.parent WHERE a.parent=" . $parent);
    echo '<select onchange="showProduct(this.value);">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row['Count'] > 0) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['link'] . "'>" . $row['label'];
            display_children($row['id'], $level + 1);
            echo "</option>";
        } elseif ($row['Count']==0) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['link'] . "'>" . $row['label'] . "</option>";
        } else;
    }
    echo "</select>";
}

display_children(0, 1);
```

The only problem is that the links will not work inside a select box. I would suggest looking into using the onchange attribute of select and using javascript to handle the logic when an item is chosen from the select box.

**Javascript:**

```
function showProduct(productLink) {
    //do something with the product value
    // maybe something like...
    location.href = productLink;
}
```

Comment: Wops. Seems that i forget to explain something. I don't need the links for the multilevel. I only need the selectbox so the user kan choose a category, where theres an id for the category in the value :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for `<optgroup>` I've never used it with multiple tiers, but it's worth a shot.

http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/optgroup/

Comment: AFAIK you can only have one level of optgroup (you can't nest an optgroup inside another optgroup).  Either way, most user agents (with the exception of IE for Mac, which is really old and not supported anymore) will not render the optgroups as submenus and will display everything in the select, which can result in really long, unusable selects.

Comment: Didn't sound to me like there would be many entries. Wasn't aware it had dropped out of uses either, curses!